# Shortcut for 'display' in Eclipse Mars

Tags: java, eclipse

I have just downloaded the newest Eclipse version "Mars.2 Release (4.5.2)". Now, in the debug mode, I wanted to `display` an expression with the shortcut `CTRL + SHIFT + D` ([like in this Eclipse shortcut overview](http://dcg.ethz.ch/lectures/ss07/vs/material/EclipseShortcuts.pdf)).

But instead of invoking the selected expression (as in older versions), in the newer version the dialog "Open Type in Diagram" appears.

Furthermore, the shortcut isn't displayed in the "right-mouse-click-menu":

[image]

Did Eclipse remove this shortcut in the recent past?

Thanks for your help!

Comment: I can confirm it doesn't work on Mac OSX either

Comment: Thx. My OS is Windows 7.

Answer (score 2):

You can change the keybindings. It's probably been nicked by another plugin extension. If you go into Window -> Preferences -> General -> Keys you can then re-assign the key press to the display command. Also note that the key may be context sensitive, so that it will be enabled when you are in the evaluation view but not otherwise.

Comment: Thanks! But I had to do an additional step: In the keys-dialog I had to change the "When"- field (of command "Display") to "Debugging", then it worked.

Comment: If you found this answer helped, you can click on the tick next to it to show it as the accepted answer.